# FTP access to a folder but not the whole filesystem

Tags: ftp, centos-7, vsftpd

I need to allow a third party to access the folder /var/spool/asterisk/monitor through FTP (vsftpd on CentoOS 7). I've created the user, tuned the vstfpd.conf file and the user can connect and access the home path (/home/ftpuser).

[root@server ~]# ll -hR /home/ftpuser/ /home/ftpuser/: total 0 dr-xr-x--- 3 ftpuser ftpuser 38 Mar 9 11:10 ftp

/home/ftpuser/ftp: total 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Mar 9 11:10 recordings -> /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/ drwxr-x--- 2 root root 6 Mar 9 11:06 upload

But as soon as the FTP client goes into /home/ftpuser/ftp/recordings/ they can go back even to / and change to any folder, they can't delete or change some files but, the client can view some config files that it should not see.

How can I prevent the user to access other folders but still access /var/spool/asterisk/monitor?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to look into chroot for this

Comment: Hi @SPRBRN, thanks for your suggestion, these are my chroot related parameters:

Hi
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

Do you see something wrong? Thanks. David